# How to get the IP Adress of an email receiver

Tags: email, user-tracking, smtp

I am communicating through email with a scammer who is trying to by me mw own parcel of land. I already contacted the police but it could take 2 to 3 months before they start investigating. I want to get the IP address of the scammer and provided it to the police. Is that possible? I tried to use different tools such as `bananatag` or `mailtrack.io` . They report me if the email was opened or not but not the IP address of the reader. I suppose such services use Pixel Images  included in the email signature. If I create my own pixel and host it on my server will I be able to get the receiver info? Is there an easier way?

Comment: Even if you have their IP address, the police aren't really going to do anything about it. You have to prove a substantial loss in profit (think $10,000 and up) in order for them to consider it worth their time. A scammer is a dime a dozen. I think there was a talk at some security con where someone used OSINT tools to track down and locate a particular Nigerian scammer. Perhaps you should look into that.

Answer (score 3):

You can pixel all you want, but they might get a message in their mail client saying that "images" or "external content" has been blocked, and they'll have to manually allow it, which might be suspicious to them.

Something I used to do is forge a story inside the situation (add a bit of social engineering to the pixel idea).
What I would do in this situation would be to send him an email:

```
I found a picture of a piece of land I'm willing to buy, please see below:
<img src="http://my.server.com/image.jpg?tag=827362923">
```

Then, you wait and later on search the web server logs with `grep 827362923`.

This has a few limitations:

- Chances are the image gets picked up by antispam on the way, so you might get false positives that hit the link, you can check this with WHOIS (e.g. https://whois.domaintools.com/[enterIPHere])
- The receiver still has to allow images to load in the mail client, but in this context, it's less suspicious than with a pixel.
- It requires you to have your own server.
- If the scammer is behind a VPN or proxy (which is very likely in most cases), you will obviously get that IP.